# Python Flask- How to access lohalhost using database server?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymysql

**file .evn**

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:3307
DB_DATABASE=bookinghotel_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**file config.py**

```
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    HOST = str(os.environ.get("DB_HOST"))
    DATABASE = str(os.environ.get("DB_DATABASE"))
    USERNAME = str(os.environ.get("DB_USERNAME"))
    PASSWORD = str(os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"))

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://' + USERNAME + '/' + PASSWORD + '@' + HOST + '/' + DATABASE
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES = True`
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'root' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please check the syntax of your ```SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI```.  It doesn't look right.  between username and password, I don't believe it is a ```/```.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering suggests that there's an issue with the way you're defining the database connection URL and hostname in your Flask configuration. To access a MySQL database server using Flask and SQLAlchemy, you should follow these steps:

First, make sure that your MySQL server is running and is accessible at the specified host (127.0.0.1) and port (3307).

Update your .env file to separate the host and port in the DB_HOST variable:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=bookinghotel_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Modify your config.py file to include the port in the database URI:

```
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    HOST = str(os.environ.get("DB_HOST"))
    PORT = str(os.environ.get("DB_PORT"))
    DATABASE = str(os.environ.get("DB_DATABASE"))
    USERNAME = str(os.environ.get("DB_USERNAME"))
    PASSWORD = str(os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"))

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD + '@' + HOST + ':' + PORT + '/' + DATABASE
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES = True
```

Ensure you import Config into your Flask application and set it as a configuration:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# ... rest of your Flask application code ...
```

Make sure that the MySQL server is running and accessible at the specified host and port. Also, verify that the MySQL service is configured to listen on port 3307 if you intended to use that port.

After these changes, your Flask application should be able to connect to the MySQL database using the provided credentials and host information.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the answer you gave was successful